# How to make the game buttons show up in a Python-based Connect Four game?

Tags: python, tkinter, connect-four

I am currently working on making a Python version of the game Connect Four. It is going to be pretty basic, using Tkinter for the interface. I think I have most of the code laid out and I'm not getting any errors, but it currently isn't creating the actual game board. Right now, I only have it coded to make the first row of 7 (the gameboard is 7x6), but it's not showing up.

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class cell:
    def __init__(self,cellNum,frame,game):
        self.Empty=PhotoImage(file='empty.gif')
        self.Black=PhotoImage(file='black.gif')
        self.Red=PhotoImage(file='red.gif')
        self.b = Button(frame,image=self.Empty,command=self.makeMove)
        self.frame = frame
        self.game = game
        self.num = cellNum
        
    def pack(self):
        self.gameSquare.pack()

    def makeMove(self):
        Player = self.game.Player
        if self.Player == 'Black':
            self.b.config(image=self.Black)
            num = self.num
            self.game.moves[Player].append(num)
            self.game.free.remove(num)
            self.Player = 'Red'
        else:
            self.b.config(image=self.Red)
            self.Player = 'Black'
        self.turninfo.config(text=Player+"'s Turn")

    def restart(self):
        self.b.config(image=self.Empty)

class game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Tk()
        self.win.title('Connect Four')
        self.win.config(bg="blue")
        self.cells=[]
        self.free = range(42)
        self.moves = { 'X' : [ ], 'O' : [ ] }
        self.Row1 = Frame(self.win)
        for i in range(7):
            self.cells.append(cell(i,self.Row1,self))
        self.Player = 'Black'

        self.titleFrame = Frame(self.win)
        self.title = Label(self.win,text="Connect Four",font=(200),fg='white', bg='blue')


        self.middleRow = Frame(self.win)
        self.turninfo = Label(self.middleRow,text=self.Player+"'s Turn", font=(200),fg='white',bg='blue')

        self.bottomRow = Frame(self.win)
        self.quitbutton = Button(self.bottomRow, text="Quit", command=self.win.destroy, font=(200))
        self.playbutton = Button(self.bottomRow, text="Play Again", command=self.restart, font=(200))

        self.titleFrame.pack()
        self.title.pack()
        self.Row1.pack()
        self.turninfo.pack()
        self.middleRow.pack()
        self.bottomRow.pack()
        self.quitbutton.pack(side="left")
        self.playbutton.pack(side="right")
        self.win.mainloop()

    def restart(self):
        self.Player = 'Black'
        self.turninfo.config(text=self.Player+"'s Turn")
        self.free = range(42)
        self.moves = {'Black' : [ ], 'Red' : [ ]}
        for c in self.cells:
            c.restart()

game = game()
```

Does anyone see any obvious errors causing the gameboard buttons not to show up? Or any errors in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to pack the buttons into the frame:

```
    self.b = Button(frame,image=self.Empty,command=self.makeMove)
    self.b.pack(side=LEFT)
```